# Development mobile application for windows based phone

Tags: android, ios, .net, windows-phone, cross-platform

I developed native iOS and Android based applications with a dot net server.
I didn't use any cross-platform capabilities.
Now I have a new requirement that enforces me to install my application on windows phone and tablet.
Do I need to develop a new window based application from scratch? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, yes. Either you'll have to rewrite the app for Windows Phone specifically or for cross-platform but I don't know any way of running a native Android app on a Windows phone.